# Web Service error al invocar un header de autenticación Java

Tags: java, webservice

Tengo el siguiente wsdl y estoy tratando de consumir el servicio desde un un web services client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
            <s:element name="Test">
                <s:complexType />
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="TestResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="s:string" />
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="AuthHeader" type="tns:AuthHeader" />
            <s:complexType name="AuthHeader">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Usuario" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
                </s:sequence>
                <s:anyAttribute />
            </s:complexType>
            <s:element name="GrabacionNovedades">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="objNovedadPaquete" type="tns:NovedadPaquete" />
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:complexType name="NovedadPaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoPaquete" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroBeneficiarios" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TienePlata" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TipoNovedad" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaAplicacion" type="s:dateTime" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Encabezado" type="tns:EncabezadoPaquete" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Contratantes" type="tns:ArrayOfContratantePaquete" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Beneficiarios" type="tns:ArrayOfBeneficiarioPaquete" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResultadoValidacion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ResultadoNumeroEncabezado" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResultadoObservacion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ResultadoFechaHoraTransaccion" type="s:dateTime" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="EncabezadoPaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TipoDocumento" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TipoContrato" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TerceraTarjetaCuenta" type="s:decimal" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TelefonoReferencia" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TelefonoContacto" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PrimerNombre" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SegundoNombre" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PrimerApellido" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SegundoApellido" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RepresentanteLegal" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReferenciaPersonoaloFamiliar" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RangoIngresosMensuales" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Ocupacion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroTarjeta" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroFormulario" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroCuotas" type="s:decimal" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroCuenta" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NombreTarjetaCuenta" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroIdentificacion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NivelEducativo" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ModalidadPago" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FormaPago" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaVencimientoTarjeta" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaNacimientoContratante" type="s:dateTime" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaInicioVigencia" type="s:dateTime" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstadoCivil" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Email" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DireccionCorrespondencia" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoSectorEconomico" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoFranquicia" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoImpuesto" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoBarrio" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoBanco" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoAsesor" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ClaveAsesor" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Ciudad" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Celular" type="s:string" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="ArrayOfContratantePaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ContratantePaquete" nillable="true" type="tns:ContratantePaquete" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="ContratantePaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroRmt_Cont" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PrimerNombre" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SegundoNombre" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PrimerApellido" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SegundoApellido" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TipoDocumento" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroDocumeto" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LugarNacimiento" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaNacimiento" type="s:dateTime" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DireccionCorrespondencia" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Ciudad" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoBarrio" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Email" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Celular" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TelefonoContacto" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NivelEducativo" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstadoCivil" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Ocupacion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RangoIngresosMensuales" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DeclaracionVoluntaria" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DescripcionDeclaracion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReferenciaPersonoaloFamiliar" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TelefonoReferencia" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RepresentanteLegal" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoAsesor" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ClaveAsesor" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroFormulario" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaInicioVigencia" type="s:dateTime" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoImpuesto" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoSectorEconomico" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ManejaRecursosPublicos" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OstentaPoderPublico" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GozaReconocimienoPublico" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EsServidorPublico" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RealizaOperacionesInternacionales" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DescripcionOperacionInternacional" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AutorizaEnvioInformacionCorreo" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AutorizaRecepcionMensajesTexto" type="s:string" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="ArrayOfBeneficiarioPaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="BeneficiarioPaquete" nillable="true" type="tns:BeneficiarioPaquete" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="BeneficiarioPaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TipoDocumentoContratante" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumeroDocumetoContratante" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NombreBeneficiario" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TipoDocumento" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Identificacion" type="s:decimal" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Genero" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FechaNacimiento" type="s:dateTime" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Parentesco" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Direccion" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoBarrio" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Ciudad" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Telefono" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Eps" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoCampana" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ValorBeneficiario" type="s:decimal" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoPLan" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Asesores" type="tns:ArrayOfAsesoresPaquete" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="ArrayOfAsesoresPaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AsesoresPaquete" nillable="true" type="tns:AsesoresPaquete" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="AsesoresPaquete">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CodigoAsesor" type="s:decimal" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ClaveAsesor" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Porcentaje" type="s:int" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:element name="GrabacionNovedadesResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GrabacionNovedadesResult" type="tns:NovedadPaquete" />
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="TestSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Test" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="TestSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="TestAuthHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GrabacionNovedadesSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GrabacionNovedades" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GrabacionNovedadesSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GrabacionNovedadesResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GrabacionNovedadesAuthHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="WebServiceGrabacionSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="Test">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Metodo de prueba que retorna string con la fecha del servidor</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:TestSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:TestSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GrabacionNovedades">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Metodo de grabacion de novedades.</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GrabacionNovedadesSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GrabacionNovedadesSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="WebServiceGrabacionSoap" type="tns:WebServiceGrabacionSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Test">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Test" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
                <soap:header message="tns:TestAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GrabacionNovedades">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GrabacionNovedades" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
                <soap:header message="tns:GrabacionNovedadesAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="WebServiceGrabacionSoap12" type="tns:WebService
                  GrabacionSoap">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Test">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Test" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
                <soap12:header message="tns:TestAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GrabacionNovedades">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GrabacionNovedades" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
                <soap12:header message="tns:GrabacionNovedadesAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="WebServiceGrabacion">
        <wsdl:port name="WebServiceGrabacionSoap" binding="tns:WebServiceGrabacionSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://xxx" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="WebServiceGrabacionSoap12" binding="tns:WebServiceGrabacionSoap12">
            <soap12:address location="http://xxxxx" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

Cuando intento llamarlo desde Java con este método:

```
   private static NovedadPaquete grabacionNovedades(org.tempuri.NovedadPaquete objNovedadPaquete) {
   org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion service = new org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion();
   org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacionSoap port = service.getWebServiceGrabacionSoap();

    return port.grabacionNovedades(objNovedadPaquete);
}
```

Me indica que debo ingresar los parámetros de autenticación que están en el header e intentado pasar los para metros de la siguiente manera

```
 private static NovedadPaquete grabacionNovedades(org.tempuri.NovedadPaquete objNovedadPaquete) {
    org.tempuri.AuthHeader a = new org.tempuri.AuthHeader();
    a.setUsuario("usuario");
    a.setPassword("contrasena");
    ObjectFactory o = new ObjectFactory();
   org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion service = new org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion();
   org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacionSoap port = service.getWebServiceGrabacionSoap();

    return port.grabacionNovedades(objNovedadPaquete);
}
```

Tampoco funciona. Alguien me podría indicar como hago para pasar el usuario y la contraseña, Las clases de autenticación que utiliza son las siguientes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AuthHeader", propOrder = {
"usuario",
"password"
})
public class AuthHeader {

@XmlElement(name = "Usuario")
protected String usuario;
@XmlElement(name = "Password")
protected String password;
@XmlAnyAttribute
private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

/**
 * Obtiene el valor de la propiedad usuario.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

/**
 * Define el valor de la propiedad usuario.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setUsuario(String value) {
    this.usuario = value;
}

/**
 * Obtiene el valor de la propiedad password.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * Define el valor de la propiedad password.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setPassword(String value) {
    this.password = value;
}

/**
 * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
 * 
 * <p>
 * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
 * the value is the string value of the attribute.
 * 
 * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
 * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
 * 
 * 
 * @return
 *     always non-null
 */
public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
    return otherAttributes;
}

}

public class ObjectFactory {

private final static QName _AuthHeader_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "AuthHeader");

/**
 * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: org.tempuri
 * 
 */
public ObjectFactory() {
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link Test }
 * 
 */
public Test createTest() {
    return new Test();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link GrabacionNovedadesResponse }
 * 
 */
public GrabacionNovedadesResponse createGrabacionNovedadesResponse() {
    return new GrabacionNovedadesResponse();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link NovedadPaquete }
 * 
 */
public NovedadPaquete createNovedadPaquete() {
    return new NovedadPaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link AuthHeader }
 * 
 */
public AuthHeader createAuthHeader() {
    return new AuthHeader();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link TestResponse }
 * 
 */
public TestResponse createTestResponse() {
    return new TestResponse();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link GrabacionNovedades }
 * 
 */
public GrabacionNovedades createGrabacionNovedades() {
    return new GrabacionNovedades();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ArrayOfContratantePaquete }
 * 
 */
public ArrayOfContratantePaquete createArrayOfContratantePaquete() {
    return new ArrayOfContratantePaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link EncabezadoPaquete }
 * 
 */
public EncabezadoPaquete createEncabezadoPaquete() {
    return new EncabezadoPaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link BeneficiarioPaquete }
 * 
 */
public BeneficiarioPaquete createBeneficiarioPaquete() {
    return new BeneficiarioPaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ArrayOfBeneficiarioPaquete }
 * 
 */
public ArrayOfBeneficiarioPaquete createArrayOfBeneficiarioPaquete() {
    return new ArrayOfBeneficiarioPaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ContratantePaquete }
 * 
 */
public ContratantePaquete createContratantePaquete() {
    return new ContratantePaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link ArrayOfAsesoresPaquete }
 * 
 */
public ArrayOfAsesoresPaquete createArrayOfAsesoresPaquete() {
    return new ArrayOfAsesoresPaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link AsesoresPaquete }
 * 
 */
public AsesoresPaquete createAsesoresPaquete() {
    return new AsesoresPaquete();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link AuthHeader }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "AuthHeader")
public JAXBElement<AuthHeader> createAuthHeader(AuthHeader value) {
    return new JAXBElement<AuthHeader>(_AuthHeader_QNAME, AuthHeader.class, null, value);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Después de muchos intentos encontré que el ID netbeans no genera los set y get de los headers de autenticación por lo tanto cree nos dos clases, las cuales básicamente borran el header que trae por defecto el web services y lo vuelven a construir y generan un log para verificar cuales son los parámetros que le envió al ws

**la primera clase es es la encargada de eliminar y crear el nuevo header**

```
public class ServerSOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

/**
 * Is called after constructing the handler and before executing any othe method.
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
}


/**
 * Returns the <code>Set</code> of supported SOAP headers
 */
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return null;
}

/**
 * Returns the message encoding (e.g. utf-8)
 * 
 * @param msg
 * @return
 * @throws javax.xml.soap.SOAPException
 */
private String getMessageEncoding(SOAPMessage msg) throws SOAPException {
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    if (msg.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING) != null) {
        encoding = msg.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING).toString();
    }
    return encoding;
}


/**
 * Dump SOAP Message to console
 * 
 * @param msg
 */
private void dumpSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage msg) {
    if (msg == null) {
        System.out.println("SOAP Message is null");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println("DUMP OF SOAP MESSAGE");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        msg.writeTo(baos);
        System.out.println(baos.toString(getMessageEncoding(msg)));

        // show included values
        String values = msg.getSOAPBody().getTextContent();
        System.out.println("Included values:" + values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * This method handles the incoming and outgoing SOAP-Message.
 * It's an excellent point to manipulate the SOAP.
 * 
 * @param SOAPMessageContext
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    //Inquire incoming or outgoing message. 
    boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    try {
        if (outbound) {
            // OUTBOUND                
            System.out.println("Direction=outbound (handleMessage)");
            SOAPMessage msg = ((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage();
            // get SOAP-Part
            SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
            //edit Envelope 
            SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();

            if(env.getHeader() != null)
            {
               env.getHeader().detachNode();                   
            }

            SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();

            SOAPElement soapElementoCabecera = soapFactory.createElement("AuthHeader","","http://tempuri.org/");

            SOAPElement headerUsuario = soapFactory.createElement("Usuario","","http://tempuri.org/");
            SOAPElement headerContrasena = soapFactory.createElement("Password","","http://tempuri.org/");

            headerUsuario.addTextNode("usuario");
            headerContrasena.addTextNode("contrasena");

            soapElementoCabecera.addChildElement(headerUsuario);
            soapElementoCabecera.addChildElement(headerContrasena);

            SOAPHeader soapHeader = env.addHeader();
            soapHeader.addChildElement(soapElementoCabecera);

            if (outbound)
            {
                try
                {
                    SOAPMessage soapmsg = context.getMessage();
                    soapmsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soap");
                    soapmsg.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soap");
                    soapmsg.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soap");

                    soapmsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                    soapmsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                    soapmsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                    soapmsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttribute("xmlns:S");
                    soapmsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttribute("xmlns:SOAP-ENV");
                }
                catch(SOAPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            msg.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION,Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            msg.saveChanges();
            }

        } else {
            // INBOUND                
            System.out.println("Direction=inbound (handleMessage)");
            SOAPMessage msg = ((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage();
            dumpSOAPMessage(msg);
         }           

    } catch (Exception e) {

        //All other unhandled problems.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * Handles SOAP-Errors.
 * 
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    System.out.println("ServerSOAPHandler.handleFault");
    boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (outbound) {
        System.out.println("Direction=outbound (handleFault)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Direction=inbound (handleFault)");
    }
    if (!outbound) {
        try {
            SOAPMessage msg = ((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage();
            dumpSOAPMessage(msg);
            if (context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault() != null) {
                String detailName = null;
                try {
                    detailName = context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault().getDetail().getFirstChild().getLocalName();
                    System.out.println("detailName=" + detailName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
}


/**
 * Is executed before this handler is being destroyed -
 * means after close() has been executed.
 */
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

**la segunda clase crea el log**

```
        public class LogMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

@Override
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage(); //Line 1
    try {
        msg.writeTo(System.out);  //Line 3
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogMessageHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void close(MessageContext context) {
}
}
```

**la manera de implementar es**

```
 private static NovedadPaquete grabacionNovedades(org.tempuri.NovedadPaquete objNovedadPaquete) {
        org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion service = new org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion();
        org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacionSoap port = service.getWebServiceGrabacionSoap();
        BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
        Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
        List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
        handlerChain.add(new LogMessageHandler());
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
        return port.grabacionNovedades(objNovedadPaquete);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente código:

```
private static NovedadPaquete grabacionNovedades(org.tempuri.NovedadPaquete objNovedadPaquete){
    org.tempuri.AuthHeader a=new org.tempuri.AuthHeader();
    a.setUsuario("usuario");
    a.setPassword("contrasena");
    ObjectFactory o=new ObjectFactory();
    org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion service=new org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacion();
    org.tempuri.WebServiceGrabacionSoap port=service.getWebServiceGrabacionSoap();
    return port.grabacionNovedades(objNovedadPaquete);}
```

Jamás usas la variable "a" de la clase "AuthHeader", en mi caso cuando se tiene un header de autenticación uso la clase que extiende de Service para colocar la autenticación. En tu caso deberias setear esa variable en alguna clase relacionada a tu WS. En todo caso mandar el codigo de "WebServiceGrabacion" y "WebServiceGrabacionSoap".

Comment: la verdad intento setearlo a las clases pero ninguana recibe un .set todas son .get

Comment: lo intente de esta manera pero tampoco lo reconoce `reqMap.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://cse.cloudapp.net:8081/ConsultasBasicas/WebServiceGrabacion.asmx");
       Map<String,List<String>> header= new HashMap<>();
       header.put("Usuario",Collections.singletonList("usuario"));
       header.put("Password",Collections.singletonList("contrasena"));
       reqMap.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,header);`

Comment: Prueba implementando un HandlerResolver, despues este lo seteas en tu codigo "service.setHandlerResolver(TuResolver)". Asi es como yo creo los tags del header para autenticación.